# Is a FIN only segment legal?

Tags: tcp, firewall, intrusion-prevention

It would be convenient to mark TCP segments with just the FIN flag set, as an intrusion (without tracking the reply).

I have always assumed that a FIN without an ACK, while rude and rare, is legal, based on [connection termination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination).

But then I read statements such as  ["A FIN will *never* appear by itself which is why Cisco's
"established" keyword filters on ACK and/or RST packets. Only FIN/ACK is
valid."](https://lists.sans.org/pipermail/list/2006-June/024563.html)

1. Is a FIN only segment legal?
2. If so, where might I encounter one and why?

Comment: According to RFC793, p. 16 "If the ACK control bit is set this field contains the value of the next sequence number the sender of the segment is expecting to receive.  Once a connection is established this is always sent."

Comment: @JeanPierre I see. Are you saying a non initiating ACKless FIN is *illegal* ( non initiating to distinguish from the T/TCP initiating SYNFIN. This seems contrary to what others have claimed.

Comment: If you have proven it is *illegal per spec*, please answer this (and the related question with bounty)

Comment: **I really hope you are correct!**

Comment: The answer to the bounty question being it would never occur!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All the research of half an hour says that FIN-only is never legitimate.

http://www.whitehats.ca/main/members/Seeker/seeker_tcp_header/seeker_tcp_header.html

> Packets should never contain just a FIN flag. FIN packets are
>   frequently used for port scans, network mapping and other stealth
>   activities.

https://lists.sans.org/pipermail/list/2006-June/024563.html

> Send an unsolicited ACK to an open or closed port and you will get
>   back a plain RST. A FIN will *never* appear by itself which is why
>   Cisco's "established" keyword filters on ACK and/or RST packets. Only
>   FIN/ACK is valid.

Other Stack Exchange sites, such as https://security.stackexchange.com/, possibly https://superuser.com/, might be better in the context of discussing IDS/IPS topics.

**EDIT:**

(With tip'o'the hat to Ron Maupin, see his comment): The TCP RFC does *not* (edited, it must've been late...)  explicitely state that a FIN only packet is illegal nor that a FIN flag MUST be accompanied by another flag. Still, a FIN only packet in a modern day network is something unusual, quite possibly intentional, this probably worth looking at and for.